# No Need for Introductions

Tags: spacechem

Does anyone know how to beat this level?  I tried my own solution and it didn't work, then I found an online guide and copied it exactly and I still can't beat it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I'm supposed to use the control switches to not fire the laser until the eye is open on the pyramid.  I guess this allows the particle accelerator to charge up more to hurt the eye while it's open instead of wasting power shooting at it while it's closed.

Comment: I've managed to beat that level without control switch and only two reactors :D

Answer (score 2):

I just had a really long pipe to store up the unwanted waste so my reactors would just keep pumping until the boss was beaten. The command centre took quite a bit of damage, but continuously firing and loading up with H202 got me through easily enough.

Comment: Apparently I did this as well - my command center was at 25% or so when I won, but I just fired that thing willy-nilly and my flow of H2O2 kept the voltage at 50% or so until it died.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to allow the particle accelerator to fire continuously, but use the controls to hold back the hydrogen peroxide until the eye opens and then let it through to increase the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

My solution didn't use any control switches, it just pushes Uranium and Hydrogen Peroxide through really fast.

Comment: hi xyzyxx, your answer does not really explain how you beat the level, would you mind clarifying it a bit for us?